Single macro for encrypting multiple types, including other macro's
So I have a bit of a complicated problem for which I need help; I want to encrypt various bits of data at compile time to obfuscate it in the final binary. This in itself is not too complicated but the following two requirements make it more difficult:

Ideally I want to use a single macro to do this for all types, which include &str and &[u8]
I want to be able to encrypt the output of other macro calls. For instance, I want to encrypt the contents of the file a.bin, of which the path is set through an environment variable, with static_encrypt!(include_bytes!(std::env!("BIN_PATH")))

For the first problem I believe this can be resolved with TT munchers? Though I did not get it to work and got the recursion limit error, so probably I did something not-so-smart :)
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! static_encrypt {
    (_ &str) => {
        println!("got &str");
    };
    (_ &[u8]) => {
        println!("got &[u8]");
    };
    (_ $tp:ty) => {
        println!("fallback to type");
    };
    ($($tp:tt)*) => {
        static_encrypt!(_ $($tp)*);
    };
}

Now I've read some posts online that say the second problem cannot be resolved as rust is non-greedy link. What would be a way to solve this without the non-obfuscated data ending up in the final binary? I assume that if you first assign it to a variable before passing it to the static_encrypt macro it will be embedded in the code without obfuscation? And how can a possible solution be combined with the first problem of having a single macro that can be called?
Perhaps this whole approach is not feasible, in which case I am more than interested in possible alternatives!
Thanks in advance!

Not sure what you mean by "encrypt", but there are very few problems that cannot be solved using proc macros.

You have to be very careful when building something like this, because if the algorithm is simple enough, the optimizer can inline the result of decryption, effectively undoing the obfuscation.
